# Rserve installation Error

Tags: r, rstudio, rjava, rserve

I want to run an R script into eclipse.

- R 3.1.1
- Ubuntu 12.04
- Eclipse Kepler
- Jars:

  - JRI.jar
  - REngine.jar
  - RserveEngine.jar
- Environment (Run -> Run Configuration -> Environment)

  - R_HOME : /usr/local/lib/R

Code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.rosuda.REngine.REXP;
import org.rosuda.REngine.REXPMismatchException;
import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection;
import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RserveException;
import org.rosuda.JRI.Rengine;

public class HelloWorldApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RserveException, REXPMismatchException, FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        RConnection c = new RConnection("localhost",6311);
        if(c.isConnected()) {
            System.out.println("Connected to RServe.");
            if(c.needLogin()) {
                System.out.println("Providing Login");
                c.login("username", "password");
            }

            REXP x = c.eval("1:10");
            for(int i=0;i < x.length();i++)
            {
                System.out.println(x.asIntegers()[i]);
            }
            System.out.println("Reading script...");
            Rengine r = new Rengine(args, true, null);

            r.eval(" plot (x");            

        } else {
            System.out.println("Rserve could not connect");
        }

        c.close();
        System.out.println("Session Closed");
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Connected to RServe.

1

2

3

4

5

6

7

8

9

10

Reading script...

Fatal error: you must specify '--save', '--no-save' or '--vanilla'
```

The same error occured in Rstudio :

```
library("Rserve")
Rserve()
```

Output:

```
Starting Rserve:
/usr/local/lib/R/bin/R CMD /home/mansi/R/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-library/3.1/Rserve/libs//Rserve 
Fatal error: you must specify '--save', '--no-save' or '--vanilla'
```

So please help me to solved this fatal error.

Comment: The code you're sending to R has a syntax error: `r.eval(" plot (x"); `. There is a missing closing parenthesis.  Try something like `r.eval(" plot (x)");`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
Try: Rserve(args='--vanilla')
```

I had the same problem, and this worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of RServe, you can use JRI, that is shipped with rJava package.

In my opinion JRI is better than RServe, because instead of creating a separate process it uses native calls to integrate Java and R.

With JRI you don't have to worry about ports, connections, watchdogs, etc... The calls to R are done using an operating system library (libjri).

The methods are pretty similar to RServe, and you can still use REXP objects.

There is an example:

```
public void testMeanFunction() {

    // just making sure we have the right version of everything
    if (!Rengine.versionCheck()) {
        System.err.println("** Version mismatch - Java files don't match library version.");
        fail(String.format("Invalid versions. Rengine must have the same version of native library. Rengine version: %d. RNI library version: %d", Rengine.getVersion(), Rengine.rniGetVersion()));
    }

    // Enables debug traces
    Rengine.DEBUG = 1;

    System.out.println("Creating Rengine (with arguments)");
    // 1) we pass the arguments from the command line
    // 2) we won't use the main loop at first, we'll start it later
    // (that's the "false" as second argument)
    // 3) no callback class will be used
    engine = REngine.engineForClass("org.rosuda.REngine.JRI.JRIEngine", new String[] { "--no-save" }, null, false);
    System.out.println("Rengine created...");

    engine.parseAndEval("rVector=c(1,2,3,4,5)");
    REXP result = engine.parseAndEval("meanVal=mean(rVector)");
    // generic vectors are RVector to accomodate names
    assertThat(result.asDouble()).isEqualTo(3.0);
}
```

I have a demo project that exposes a REST API and calls R functions using this package.

Take a look at: https://github.com/jfcorugedo/RJavaServer